# Grabbing when a UIImagePickerController takes a picture

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController like so:

```
    // Start picker code
    UIImagePickerController *photo = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photo.delegate = self;
    photo.allowsEditing = NO;
    //photo.showsCameraControls = NO;
    photo.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    cameraView.frame = photo.cameraOverlayView.frame;
    photo.cameraOverlayView = cameraView;



    // photo.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    //[photo setCameraOverlayView:cameraView];

    [self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I see the -(void) takePicture in the docs, but how do I run code when the picture is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

By registering `self` as a delegate of `UIImagePickerController` you can overwrite `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate